# Multi-tabbed Excel Reporting Tool

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, business-intelligence

Which is a popular reporting tool out there to automate Multi-tabbed excel reports. I need a tool which connects to a db., we can create multi-tab reports in it, and have it send automated reports on a weekly basis.

I have previously worked with Crystal Reports and Logi Analytics tool.
Is there any other tool in the market?

The multi-tabbed reports are tabular data separated by different kinds of grouping.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3rd-party Crystal Reports automation tools that can export Crystal Reports data into multi-tab excel workbooks. Ken Hamady maintains a listing of 3rd-party tools [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#desktopsched).

It may help to suggest the best approach if you describe your use case in more details. What do you need in the resulting multiple tabs: tabular data? Pivot tables/charts? formatted reports? Do you need to burst a single data set into multiple tabs by some grouping logic?